# Can someone debug this html code for a carousel?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

HI am using the following code snippet using bootstrap to make a carousel. The next and prev buttons do not switch the content.

```
<div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item ">
    <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
    <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <h2 >My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
    <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: When I tried your code it worked for me can you explain about your bug in detail

Comment: The slide does not switch to the next carousel item basically on pressing the buttons, it stays on the initial "carousel-item active" element.

Comment: you want to slide when you click and auto slide  right !

Answer (score 0):

Compare your slider with this code . Your code property is auto slide . You can get all kind of carousel [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/)

```
<div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item ">
    <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
    <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <h2 >My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
    <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
</a>
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the neccessary libraries.

Add these in your HTML:
In the Head tag :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

After the body Tag:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Order should be maintained.